# TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'size' of op 'Slice', got [4608.0] of type 'list' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a deep learning model in keras and i am getting this error

```
TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'size' of op 'Slice', got [4608.0] of type 'list' instead. Error: Expected int32, got 4608.0 of type 'float' instead.
```

I even tried changing my model, but error is still there
Here is my model

```
def ourmodel(numberOfLSTMcells=3,n_timesteps_in=3000,n_features=61):

    inp =Input(shape=(n_timesteps_in, n_features))
    lstm= LSTM(numberOfLSTMcells,return_sequences=True, return_state=False) (inp)
    flatten=Flatten()(lstm)
    fc=Dense(64,activation='relu')(flatten)
    fc=Dense(32,activation='relu')(fc)
    out=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(fc)

    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model=ourmodel()
model.fit(data_array,y=label_array,batch_size=1024*0.1,epochs=50,verbose=0)
```

Here is shape of my data

```
data_array: ((5078, 3000, 61), 
label_array: (5078,))
```

Error logs

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    329   try:
--> 330     fn(values)
    331   except ValueError as e:

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in inner(values)
    268                issubclass(v.dtype.type, expected_types))):
--> 269         _check_failed(v)
    270 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _check_failed(v)
    249   # it is safe to use here.
--> 250   raise ValueError(v)
    251 

ValueError: 4608.0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    516           else:
--> 517             values = ops.convert_to_tensor(
    518                 values,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1539     if ret is None:
-> 1540       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1541 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    338   _ = as_ref
--> 339   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    340 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    263   """
--> 264   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    265                         allow_broadcast=True)

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    280   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 281       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    282           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    456     else:
--> 457       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    458       nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    335     else:
--> 336       raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." %
    337                       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))

TypeError: Expected int32, got 4608.0 of type 'float' instead.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_21106/972192804.py in <module>
      1 model=ourmodel()
----> 2 model.fit(data_array,y=label_array,batch_size=1024*0.5,epochs=50,verbose=0)

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1048          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1049       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
-> 1050       data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
   1051           x=x,
   1052           y=y,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1098 
   1099     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1100     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1101         x,
   1102         y,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    351       return flat_dataset
    352 
--> 353     indices_dataset = indices_dataset.flat_map(slice_batch_indices)
    354 
    355     dataset = self.slice_inputs(indices_dataset, inputs)

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in flat_map(self, map_func)
   1835       Dataset: A `Dataset`.
   1836     """
-> 1837     return FlatMapDataset(self, map_func)
   1838 
   1839   def interleave(self,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func)
   4282     """See `Dataset.flat_map()` for details."""
   4283     self._input_dataset = input_dataset
-> 4284     self._map_func = StructuredFunctionWrapper(
   4285         map_func, self._transformation_name(), dataset=input_dataset)
   4286     if not isinstance(self._map_func.output_structure, DatasetSpec):

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
   3523       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
   3524         # TODO(b/141462134): Switch to using garbage collection.
-> 3525         self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
   3526         if add_to_graph:
   3527           self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3049       **kwargs: inputs to specialize on.
   3050     """
-> 3051     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
   3052         *args, **kwargs)
   3053     graph_function._garbage_collector.release()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3017       args, kwargs = None, None
   3018     with self._lock:
-> 3019       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3020       seen_names = set()
   3021       captured = object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
   3516           attributes=defun_kwargs)
   3517       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
-> 3518         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3519         ret = structure.to_tensor_list(self._output_structure, ret)
   3520         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3451         nested_args = (nested_args,)
   3452 
-> 3453       ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
   3454       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
   3455       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    665       try:
    666         with conversion_ctx:
--> 667           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    394 
    395   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_allowlisted(f):
--> 396     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
    397 
    398   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    476 
    477   if kwargs is not None:
--> 478     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    479   return f(*args)
    480 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in slice_batch_indices(indices)
    336       """
    337       num_in_full_batch = num_full_batches * batch_size
--> 338       first_k_indices = array_ops.slice(indices, [0], [num_in_full_batch])
    339       first_k_indices = array_ops.reshape(
    340           first_k_indices, [num_full_batches, batch_size])

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in slice(input_, begin, size, name)
   1101     A `Tensor` the same type as `input_`.
   1102   """
-> 1103   return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
   1104 
   1105 

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in _slice(input, begin, size, name)
   9388       pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   9389   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
-> 9390   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
   9391         "Slice", input=input, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)
   9392   _result = _outputs[:]

~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    525             raise err
    526           else:
--> 527             raise TypeError(
    528                 "Expected %s passed to parameter '%s' of op '%s', got %s of "
    529                 "type '%s' instead. Error: %s" %
```

Comment: Your batch size is not an integer..`batch_size=int(1024*0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your batch_size to
`batch_size = int(1024*0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

You provide the model with a batch size of `batch_size=1024*0.1` which is a float number. The `4608.0` is `45 * batch_size`. If you use `tf.data.Dataset` API, you should not use the `batch_size` of `tf.keras.Model.fit()` method.